# Cannot Dereference Class Object Pointers Inserted Into a Vector

Tags: c++, class, pointers, vector

```
struct Tree_Node
{
    typedef int node_value_type;

    Tree_Node(node_value_type key) : value(key) {}

public:
    node_value_type value = 0;
    Tree_Node* right = nullptr;
    Tree_Node* left = nullptr;
};
```

After inserting pointers to the above class into a vector, trying to pop an element and dereference it gives me an ``Access Violation Reading Location'' exception in Visual C++.

```
vector<Tree_Node*> node_list(2);

Tree_Node* node1 = new Tree_Node(5);

node_list.push_back(node1);

cout << node_list.front()->value;
```

However, the following works fine:

```
Tree_Node* node2 = node1;

cout << node2->value << endl;
```

What am I missing out on here?

Please note that I am adding and accessing the vector elements inside the same scope. Additionally, I am also aware of possible memory leaks and cleaning up. I just wish to know why the above code isn't working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
vector<Tree_Node*> node_list(2);
```

it creates a vector with two null pointers.

```
node_list.push_back(node1);
```

it inserts a third element

```
cout << node_list.front()->value;
```

it tries to access the first, which is a null pointer

---

To reserve space without inserting elements use:

```
vector<Tree_Node*> node_list;
node_list.reserve(2);
```

But I'm almost sure that the default ctor reserves place for more than 2 elements.

You can also update the two allocated elements:

```
vector<Tree_Node*> node_list(2);
node_list[0] = node1;
node_list[1] = node2;
```

And if you want to make sure that your container contains only two elements use an `std::pair` or (if you can use C++11) an `std::array`.

Comment: My bad, that must be it. The reason I specified the size explicitly was because I wanted to restrict the default allocation size. Basically, I want an empty vector of two elements to which I can add my two pointers. What do you feel is the best work-around for this?